# Configure Mocha unit tests after creating project using @vue/cli 3

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, vue-cli-3, vue-test-utils

Created a project using vue/cli version 3.2.1.

Trying to configuring Mocha unit testing in vue/cli 3, but no success.

Any help appreciated